# How to get the value of self.request.user when using the react application with DRF API

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I want to filter results on user basis. But I don't know How to do this

I know one way which is sending USERNAME AND PASSWORD in headers using Axios in react. But for that, I need to store username and password in react local storage.

I just want to know If I can use the username and Access token instead of USERNAME AND PASSWORD to get the value of self.request.user??

```
    def get_queryset(self):

        return TransactionData.objects.filter(
            Q(trans_receiver_id=self.request.user) | Q(trans_sender_id=self.request.user))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the token in the header and Django will fetch the user itself using the token

Answer (score 0):

Similar question is answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23239026/10798048

This might also answer your query.